# Infinite sum of squares

Tags: sequences-and-series

It is known that $1 + \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{16} + \cdots = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$
. Find the sum
$1 + \frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{25} + \frac{1}{49} + \cdots$.

What method can we use to answer this?  I tried expressing the 2nd equation into 2 fractions which contain the first summation but i couldnt find one

Comment: In fact Euler's solution to the sum of the reciprocals of the squares started with the sum of the reciprocals of the odd squares: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#Euler.27s_approach

Answer (score 4):

The usual trick: separate even and odd indices of the sum *(things converge absolutely, so you can)*.

We have $$\frac{\pi^2}{6}
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)^2}
+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}
$$
but
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)^2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4n^2}
= \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{1}{4}\frac{\pi^2}{6}
$$
so
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{1}{4}\frac{\pi^2}{6} = \frac{\pi^2}{8}\,.
$$

Answer (score 3):

$S = 1 +  \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{25} + \frac{1}{36} +...  $

Take 1/4 common from the terms whose denominator is even.

$S = 1 +  \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{25} + ... +  \frac{1}{4} ( 1 + \frac{1}{4} +  \frac{1}{9} + ... ) $

$S = 1 +  \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{25} + ... +  \frac{1}{4} S$

$ 1 +  \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{25} + ...=    \frac{3}{4} S = (3/4)(\pi^2 /6) $

Comment: Clement C. answered while I was writing this answer, but still I will leave this answer here.